# The phpMyAdmin configuration storage not completely configured

Tags: phpmyadmin

When logging into phpMyAdmin, I see the following message at the bottom of the main panel :

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
      Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

I understand this is about activating special features in phpMyAdmin, by editing the config file and creating a special database and user. However, any attempt to do so has been futile. It appears that the 'favorite' and 'central columns' tables have been deactivated.

Can anyone guide me through ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what server are you using, like wamp?

Comment: No. Sorry, I should have stated that. I use a phpMyAdmin version 4.4.14, in XAMPP, the database server is MySQL version 5.6.26

Comment: i suggest you try to uninstall current xampp server,  again install in another drive (D:/xammp)

Comment: I only have a single C drive. Can you explain what difference it makes to select alternative drives ?

Comment: xampp folder remains after uninstalling

Comment: Did you try importing the sql/create_tables.sql file?

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is "phpmyadmin configuration storage has been deactivated"

then go to:
if phpmyadmin database exists else xampp would give link to create it.

phpmyadmin >user accounts > see the permissions where permission isn't granted

[snapshot:1-Go to user accounts in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2B6U.png)

Goto the account which haven't got permissions and click on it's action tab and check the check all > and then click on Go or confirm the decision.

[then goto action option of that account and check all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW766.png)

Finally problem will be solved.